# Rails: printing an image for each cycle of a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm making a cooking recipe app and recipes have "ratings" (an integer). I want to make it so that it prints out a star for each 1 rating point (if the rating = 4, then 4 stars would print out). However, my loop is not printing out anything. Can anyone help with how I should loop through it?

```
<div>
    <h4>Rating:</h4>
    <%= @recipe.rating.times{ |i| image_tag("star.jpg") } %>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm just using it as a placeholder for now. It's not a method, I'll edit it to make it assets/starpic.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=` in front of the loop won't work the way you expect it. Use it like this:

```
<div>
    <h4>Rating:</h4>
    <% @recipe.rating.times do |i| %>
        <%= image_tag(locationofstarpic) %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

You could also print directly to the repsonse from the inline block, but it's not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the statement

```
5.times { "foo" }
```

is 5, not anything from inside the block. So what you need is this:

```
<% @recipe.rating.times do |i| %>
  <%= image_tag(locationofstarpic) %>
<% end %>
```